# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation issue with uiview frame

Tags: ios

I use this code below to change my view center:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self setUpViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

-(void)setUpViewForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
    {
        self.imagesView.center = CGPointMake(40, 40);

        [self.imagesView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

but the colour for uiview is changed but location is not, what can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Call `setUpViewForOrientation` in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method instead of `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self setUpViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

As described in the documentation:

> By the time this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property
>   is already set to the new orientation, and the bounds of the view have
>   been changed. Thus, you can perform any additional layout required by
>   your views in this method.

The nice "side effect" of using this method is that your layout changes will be animated during the rotation.